# How to semantically name divs according to HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I have this http://demetriad.co.uk/designtest.jpg which I am gonna transform in html, using HTML5 and CSS3.
Having all these paragraphs in the content area, how is it better to name them, where do I use aside, how would you do? The photo will actually be a slideshow with photos from Flickr, taken out of a JSON feed with jQuery.

Any relevant articles on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on your layout, I'd say just to use as many of the HTML5-native semantic elements as you can:

- Your "logo" text should definitely be a header. Whether a `<h1>`, or a lower-level header, is up to you / your website structure.
- The slideshow probably should just be on its own in a `<div>` - there's not really a good HTML element for it, and it's bad for semantics to try and stretch something to count for more than it should.
- Finally, looking at the main section, there's a few things that can be broken down in there:

  - The "About" text should definitely be another header, lower in number than that of the "logo" text.
  - "We design for functionality..." could probably be encapsulated in a `<blockquote>` tag.
  - The "Amazon Web Services" and "TYPO3" sections on the right could probably be put into an `<aside>` tag, as they're not directly related to the rest of the "about" section.

Generally, the best call is just to go with your gut instinct, and if you're still confused, do a quick check through a full HTML-element listing, and see if any of HTML's many tags describe your content correctly.